# How would you align something like feet?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I haven't really used Blender before and don't really know what to even look up to find out so it's probably really simple, but how would I make sure something like feet stayed perfectly flat on the ground? (Not rotated or moved up/down)

I found a lot about aligning vertices along an arbitrary line but I don't know how to make it work with a "floor"
[image: Snip of the feet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just started using blending myself.

Have you tried using G (grab) and then pressing Z so you can your object and align it to the grid?

Another option you have is to drop down the Transform panel in the top right corner, by the Options drop down menu and the four different circles.
From this panel you can use the Location X Y Z values to tell Blender exactly where you want your feet to rest!

I hope this helped and good luck!